# fseek, what does it mean to be to the last byte of a file?

Tags: c, file, fseek

This question popped up in a quiz:

Replace ‘Z’ with the proper number to set the FILE pointer ‘fp’ to the last byte of the file:

```
fseek( fp, Z, SEEK_END );
```

My answer was -1 because to me, it seemed natural that being at a certain byte meant being at a position such that appending to that file would overwrite that byte keep storing other bytes if any. The teacher insists on 0. I would appreciate if you could explain.

Comment: Hmm, there is no way for us to tell whether you translated the teacher's question from Georgian to English correctly.  The teacher said you didn't, so be it.

Comment: It is an SDSU program, so it was in English. That is the exact question in English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-1 appears to be correct. I just tried it, and an `fgetc` after `fseek(f, -1, SEEK_END)` produced the last character of the file. Seeking to 0 relative to `SEEK_END` resulted in `fgetc` returning `EOF`.

Clearly pointing to the last byte of a file is different from pointing to the end of the file. Furthermore, if there is any ambiguity in terminology, it is a failure of the test, not of the student. If the student has demonstrated the expected knowledge, they should receive credit.

Comment: Note that this is implementation-dependent.  It's undefined behavior to use `fseek()` to seek to the end of a file opened in binary mode: "A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a `whence`
value of `SEEK_END`.", and it's also undefined behavior to use `SEEK_END` and a non-zero offset on a file opened in text mode: "For a text stream, either
`offset`
shall be zero, or
`offset`
shall be a value returned by
an earlier successful call to the
`ftell`
function..."  So in strictly-conforming C code, it can't be done.